# Foursquare search venues with "intend = browse" always return 0 results

Tags: foursquare

My app is in the app store and all worked well but now foursquare has changed something and I can't get any places.

I search places in area and use `"intend" = "browse"`. I researched that if change `"intend"` to `"checkin"` it works well, but I need `"browse"`.

Additionally if I choose `"checkin"` I need to add `"ll"` parameter that I sometimes don't have.

My request:

> https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&intent=browse&query=subway&v=20140806&m=foursquare&ne=59.969420,30.265150&sw=59.871682,30.388964&limit=50&categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d1c5941735&ll=59.920551,30.327057

Response:

```
{
meta = {
        code = 200;
       };
    response = {
        venues = ();
               };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this, i garbled ne and sw with nw and se.
Remember that ne - top right corner,
sw - bottom left.